# Removing new line characters in PresentationML document

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to use a formatted PPTX file to insert my own data into the tags. In some cases however, I need to remove the tag and back up a line in the <problem> and <problemNoTab> sections. In OOXML however, xml tags are used to handle such a case, so "\n" characters are not visible. I'm not sure how to proceed since I can't do typical  tag matching either.

the template's code is as follows:

```
  <p:txBody>
   <a:bodyPr>
    <a:normAutofit />
   </a:bodyPr>
  <a:lstStyle />
  <a:p>
   <a:r>
    <a:rPr lang="en-US" b="1" dirty="0" smtClean="0" />
    <a:t>Problem</a:t>
   </a:r>
  </a:p>
  <a:p>
    <a:pPr marL="914400" indent="-914400" />
    <a:r>
     <a:rPr lang="en-US" sz="1000" smtClean="0" />
     <a:t>&lt;Problem&gt;</a:t>
    </a:r>
    <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1000" dirty="0" smtClean="0" />
  </a:p>
  <a:p>
     <a:pPr marL="0" indent="0" />
     <a:r>
      <a:rPr lang="en-US" sz="1000" dirty="0" smtClean="0"/>
          <a:t>&lt;ProblemNoTab&gt;</a:t>
     </a:r>
     <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1000" dirty="0" smtClean="0" />
  </a:p>
```

Any hints on how to remove break lines or other places to look would be greatly appreciated. I have tried basic escape characters in string replacement such as "\b" and the delete character.

Answer (score 2):

I found my solution. In C#, I have a collection of `DocumentDrawing.Text` objects, the one that I want to remove, I simply use `textPart.Parent.Parent.Remove()` and it removes the paragraph, essentially removing the new line.

Don't know if this will be useful to anyone but it worked for me.